# svn backup - how much space do I need?

Tags: svn

I have an svn repo which is 17G in size. I tried to take svnadmin dump of the repo and the dump size is 42G. Why is it so huge?

Also, I would like to try a hotcopy of the same repo. But before I could compelte it, I ran out of disk space. What size will be a hotcopy of an svn repo? I expected both to be equal or lesser in size!!

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VisualSVN Server, don't miss the latest 3.6.x release family. [VisualSVN Server 3.6](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/visualsvn-server-3.6-released) introduces a built-in backup solution with support for [scheduled incremental repo backup](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/).

> I have an svn repo which is 17G in size. I tried to take svnadmin dump
>   of the repo and the dump size is 42G. Why is it so huge?

Have you tried putting it into an archive?

Portable SVN repository dumps generated when you run [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) without any additional options a are usually larger than repos on disk because every revision is represented in dump streams in full text. You could run `svnadmin dump` with [`--deltas`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.deltas) option to make the dump make us of deltification. Note that this option could increase CPU load when generating or loading the dump as well as time to generate or load it. However, it will help you save space in case its important for you. BTW, don't forget that SVN repository dumps contain revision history only.

> What size will be a hotcopy of an svn repo? I expected both to be equal or lesser in size!!

Another tool - [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.hotcopy.html) - generates a copy of the repository on disk that will have exactly the same size and content as the source repository. Unlike SVN repo sump, hotcopy is a fully functional repository and it also includes hook scripts. The hotcopy has the same database format version as its source.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. very helpful